# Understand the Oracle Bug Database

Tags: java, oracle

As of the Release of the java 7 u40 I’ve been looking at the Bug that prevents me from Debugging Applets via Remote Debugger in Java 7u21 and 7u25.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8016005

The Bug info says that 7u40 is still affected by that Bug, and that Java 8 will fix this, but in the comments they say that in 7u40 it should work, if I understand everything properly.

Can someone enlighten me which one is the true truth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very clear that it was fixed by fixing another bug:

> It's already fixed in 7u40 (fixed as a part of 8020558)

Also the bug is already in "Fixed" state and marked as "Resolved".

Comment: But why does it say: Affected Versions:
7u21,7u40. Am i the only one who gets confused by that?

Comment: I guess it's because the fix wasn't planned for this release. In the bug description is u40 **latest build** mentioned. So that doesn't refer to the latest final release build.